# PAssert not executing and test always passing in unbounded source

Tags: java, apache-beam

I a writing simple test case to check generate Sequence is emitting elements as per duration.
Source code

```
 pipeline.apply("Source", buildSource(options))
        .apply("Windowing", defineWindow(options))
       .apply("processingState", ParDo.of(new JdbcIoPreProcessing(duration)))

 protected PTransform<? super PBegin, PCollection<Long>> buildSource(PipelineDefaultOptions pipelineDefaultOptions) {
        return GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(1, Duration.standardSeconds(options.getPollingDuration()));
    }
protected Window<Long> defineWindow(PipelineDefaultOptions pipelineDefaultOptions) {
        OrdersPipelineOptions options = (OrdersPipelineOptions) pipelineDefaultOptions;
        return Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(options.getPollingDuration())));
    }
```

TestCase

```
 Pipeline pipeline = TestPipeline.create()
                .enableAbandonedNodeEnforcement(false);
 pipeline.getOptions().as(DirectOptions.class).setBlockOnRun(false);
 PCollection<Long> actual = pipeline.apply(application.buildSource(options));
 PAssert.that(actual).containsInAnyOrder(10l)
 PipelineResult result = pipeline.run();
        PipelineResult.State state = result.waitUntilFinish(Duration.standardSeconds(10));
        result.cancel();
```

Is this PAssert correct, or how to put PAssert in this scenario. I see in the docs, window has to be provided.

I tried interval window, bounded window
IntervalWindow windowFirstEvent = new IntervalWindow(baseTime.plus(Duration.standardSeconds(0)),
baseTime.plus(Duration.standardSeconds(options.getPollingDuration())));

```
BoundedWindow window = new BoundedWindow() {
    @Override
    public Instant maxTimestamp() {
        return baseTime.plus(Duration.standardSeconds(100));
    }
};
```

PAssert.that(actual).inWindow(windowFirstEvent).containsInAnyOrder(10l)
but getting casting exception
cannot be cast to org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.windowing.GlobalWindow
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use the TestStream when testing streaming pipelines. The TestStream is an invaluable streaming source that allows you to mock out both wall-time clock and watermark advancements. See this [blog post](https://beam.apache.org/blog/test-stream/) and the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.35.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/testing/TestStream.html).

For your case, (this solution is not tested, feel free to edit afterwards), it can look something like this:

```
TestStream<int> buildSource(PipelineOptions options) {
  TestStream.Builder<int> testStreamBuilder = new TestStream.create<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TIME; ++i) {
    testStreamBuilder
      .addElements(i) 
      .advanceProcessingTime(
          Duration.standardSeconds(options.getPollingDuration()));
  }

  return testStreamBuilder.advanceWatermarkToInfinity();
}

 pipeline.apply("Source", buildSource(options))
         .apply("Windowing", defineWindow(options))
         .apply("processingState", ParDo.of(new JdbcIoPreProcessing(duration)))
```